# HttpWebRequest times out calling WCF Service using mono on Raspberry Pi

Tags: mono, timeout, raspberry-pi, system.net.httpwebrequest

I have installed mono on a raspberry pi model a, running Devian.
I can use an HTTPWebRequest to call a regular web page, but calling a WCF service causes the call to timeout.
Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace TestWeb
{
    class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        var r = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create ("https://eventboardstaging2.falafel.com/ConferenceService2/ConferenceListEx?dummy=634924037818870000");
        r.Method = "POST";
        r.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

        string json = "{\"PrivateLabel\":\"\",\"UserID\":\"46bff210-95fb-4292-8fe8-e3d99c86b97d\",\"UtcCutoff\":null}";

        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

        using (var req = r.GetRequestStream()) {
            req.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            using (var response = r.GetResponse()) {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())) {
                    var s = sr.ReadToEnd ();
                    Console.WriteLine (s.Substring(1,100));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Stack trace is

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: The request timed out
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in    <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at TestWeb.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.Net.WebException: The request timed out
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at TestWeb.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: List the stacktrace please, if possible.

Comment: OK, added the stack trace.

Comment: Does the same code work in normal Mono or on Windows?

Comment: Yes, it works in Windows on all versions of the .net framework. I read something in some forum, I forget where, about webrequest specifically to WCF services timing out.

Comment: I had a similar problem, probably caused by this bug: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805729/datetime-tostring-in-mono-return-invalid-date-00-734718-0001-014138](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805729/datetime-tostring-in-mono-return-invalid-date-00-734718-0001-014138)

Comment: @weberph - where is the date problem in this? cant figure out where DateTime come in use here. Please explain us.

Comment: @BerggreenDK - the DateTime problem was caused by the hard-float version of raspbian. WCF seems to rely on DateTime internally, maybe for handling timeouts?

Comment: Strange, because my own tests (so far and uncomplete though) shows me that DateTime works okay on Raspberry, if I retreive the values one at a time, like DateTime.month etc.