# DateTime differences between Windows and Mono, and log4net remote appender

Tags: c#, datetime, mono, log4net, utc

I have a program running on a Linux box under Mono 2.10.9. It logs to a program on a Windows 7 box using log4net. My Linux system clock is set to local time, as well as my Windows machine. Executing the following yields slightly different results on each machine:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - Kind {1}", now, now.Kind));
```

On Windows, I get

> 5/28/2013 8:39:09 PM - Kind local

and on Linux I get

> 0/735016/0001 8:39:45 PM - Kind local

It appears the conversion is corrupted in Mono, but that's another problem for another day.

In the `LoggingEvent` objects I receive from the Linux machine, the `TimeStamp` field actually contains the time in UTC, not local. However, the `TimeStamp.Kind` property is `Local`!

This is causing me problems because the log events that originate on Windows are really local, while the log events from Mono are UTC, and I can't tell the difference with `Kind`, and it looks kind of funny to have log messages that were created moments apart look like they are 5 hours apart.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: What does `TimeZoneInfo.Local` on Mono give you? Perhaps it doesn't have a good understanding of the local time zone. If you call `ToUniversal`, what happens?

Comment: Interesting, I get a `System.TimeZoneNotFoundException` when I access `TimeZoneInfo.Local`. This is a clue... However, `ToUniveralTime()` gives the proper result, so Mono must have an idea of what the timezone is. Could this have anything to do with the hardfloat problem? I'm going to download and install a softfloat distro right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best practice would be to always record log times as UTC:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

This avoids several problems:

- Gaps when Daylight Saving Time starts
- Duplication / Ambiguity when Daylight Saving Time stops
- Log files from different machines not aligning due to time zone settings

Additionally, if these are *servers* you are talking about, you should also set the time zone of the machine to UTC.  That way, other logs on the system will also match up at the same times, even if they are set to record local values.

Also, be aware that Windows wants the computer bios to be set to local time, while Linux wants it at UTC.  This can cause some interesting behaviors, especially with virtual machines, if multiple VMs are running with different operating systems or if host and guest OS are different.  Setting the local time zone to UTC avoids this.

Regarding the strange output of `DateTime.ToString()` in Mono - are you by chance running on a Raspberry Pi?  This is a known bug.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15342062/634824) and the issue linked from there.

I am not sure why you are getting UTC values instead of local values from Log4Net's `LoggingEvent.TimeStamp`, since [these docs](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Core.LoggingEvent.TimeStamp.html) say it is local.  However, it is possible you are using an appender that sends the UTC timestamp instead.  In [the FAQ](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#distributed), there is a question that talks about UTC transmitted by a `RemotingAppender`.  You might be doing something similar.  I don't know for sure, since you didn't show that part of your code.

Comment: You're correct on all accounts! I am using `RemoteAppender`, which does indeed transmit UTC timestamps, but when I receive them, the `TimeStamp.Kind` is set to local. Perhaps a bug in log4net? Excellent answer, but doesn't directly address the UTC/Local issue. If no better answer comes along, you will definitely get the bounty. And now to install a soft-float on my RPi this weekend...

Comment: Possibly they are handling the `Kind` wrong.  But more likely just fallout from the bad design of `DateTime`.  Have you read [these](http://noda-time.blogspot.com/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html) [articles](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/)?

Comment: I'm starting to think this is due to the RPi hard-float, but can't confirm it since the version of Mono I can get for the soft-float Raspbian doesn't support other functionality in my software. You get the bounty, though, since the answer was filled with a ton of info. Thanks!